# How to create a datatable based on multiple variables in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, format, quantile, cdf

I have 6 variables that I made based on the quantile function (I created different quantiles on top of the default amount of '0.25, .5, and .75'. I would like to create a summary table similar to the output below but with my variables. Any help would be much appreciated.

I used cbind to merge all the variables together in a table but the format is off.

```
ten_quantile = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .1)
twenty_quantile = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .2)
thirty_quantile = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .3)
med = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .5)
sixty_quantile = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .6)
upper = quantile(tt$HPTACC, probs = .75)


rr <- cbind(ten_quantile, twenty_quantile, thirty_quantile, med, sixty_quantile, upper)
rr

ten_quantile twenty_quantile thirty_quantile   med sixty_quantile   upper
10%       7172.1        17137.72         22099.3 29542          32302 35864.5
```

However I would like to have something like this but with the additional quantiles:

```
Sfttime <- quantile(tt$HPTACC)


## Create quantile soft time into df ##
SummaryTable <- data.frame(
  Sfttime)

      Sfttime
0%        0.00
10%   #
20%   #
25%   20072.25
35%   #
50%   29542.00
60%   #
75%   35864.50
100% 889368.00
```

Comment: `as.matrix(quantile(mtcars$mpg, probs = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, 0.35, 0.5, 0.6, 0.75, 1)))`?

Comment: Did either of our answers work for you? If so, do choose one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the **quantile()** function. You can configure the values in the *probs* argument. I will use **mtcars** as an example, but it should work with your data

```
QuantData <- quantile(mtcars$drat)
QuantData <- as.data.frame(QuantData)

Result <- data.frame(Quantile = row.names(QuantData), 
                     Value = QuantData[,1])

QuantData <- quantile(mtcars$drat, 
                      probs = c(0,0.1,0.20,0.25,0.35,0.5,0.6,0.75,1))
QuantData <- as.data.frame(QuantData)

Result <- data.frame(Quantile = row.names(QuantData), 
                     Value = QuantData[,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use dplyr's enframe:

```
quantile(tt$HPTACC, c(0,0.1,0.20,0.25,0.35,0.5,0.6,0.75,1)) %>% 
  enframe(name = "quantile")
```

Using mtcar's mpg as an example, it produces the following output:

```
> quantile(mtcars$mpg, c(0,0.1,0.20,0.25,0.35,0.5,0.6,0.75,1)) %>% 
+   enframe(name = "quantile")
# A tibble: 9 x 2
  quantile value
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 0%        10.4
2 10%       14.3
3 20%       15.2
4 25%       15.4
5 35%       17.2
6 50%       19.2
7 60%       21  
8 75%       22.8
9 100%      33.9
```